# Прилепить три блока по вертикали к одному большому блоку

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.

Есть пример, взятый из одного урока, расположенный по адресу http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/ViewModeSwitch/ , нужно добавить табы слева, как на скриншоте

[image]

Как можно реализовать? Не силен в верстке, вроде вещь мелочная, и думаю, мне смогут помочь. :-) По сути, это три блока с абсолютным позиционированием нужны или как?

Comment: position: fixed

Comment: как вариант http://jsfiddle.net/we6kppgr/

Comment: Спасибо за вариант, попробую адаптировать под свои нужды. Обожаю этот сайт, раньше на гугл ответах, толковые ребята сидели, сейчас по уровню ответов этот сайт спасает)